# How to set one image relatively to another one for any screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

There are three images: body of audiotape

[image]

and two wheels

[image]

I need to set wheels exactly on their position for all screen resolutions.

```html
<div class="tape">
    <img id="tape-body" src="{% static "web_player/images/tape_body.png" %}">
    <img id="tape-wheel-right" src="{% static "web_player/images/tape_wheel.png" %}">
    <img id="tape-wheel-left" src="{% static "web_player/images/tape_wheel.png" %}">
</div>
```

```css
.tape {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the position of the div to absolute, and then positioning the wheels relatively?

Comment: @KyleJones, I did. When I'm changing screen resolution everything breaks down

Comment: I'd suggest doing some research into media queries then. They allow you to set different CSS properties on the same elements for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is set fixed size for `div` and the same size for tape body. Then fit wheels with bottom ant left properties relatively.

```css
.tape {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
}

#tape-body {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

#tape-wheel-right {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    bottom: 176px;
    left: 91px;
}

#tape-wheel-left {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    bottom: 176px;
    left: 197px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set your `#tape-inner-right` and `#tape-inner-left` to absolute, using `vw` unit for dimensions so it resizes with the viewport width:

```css
.tape{
  height:30vw;
  width:60vw;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
}
#tape-body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#tape-wheel-left, #tape-wheel-right{
  height:10vw;
  width:10vw;
  border-radius:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:10vw;
}
#tape-wheel-left{
  left:15vw;
}
#tape-wheel-right{
  left:35vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="tape">
  <img id="tape-body" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/000/222">
  <img id="tape-wheel-left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/888/aaa">
  <img id="tape-wheel-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/888/aaa">
</div>
```

This will be able to resize with the browser/viewport.

You will just have to do the math yourself to adjust the exact position and dimensions based on what those are for your images.